# Showing $\phi(x) = x -2\sin(x)\frac{1}{2}e^x$ is iteration function for $4\sin(x)-e^x$

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

If I were to find an interation function for

$$4\sin(x)-e^x$$

I would do something like:

$$e^x = 4\sin(x)\implies x = \ln 4\sin(x) \implies x_{n+1} = \ln 4\sin(x_n)$$

or something with $\arcsin$, but I don't know how to arrive at 
$$\phi(x) = x -2\sin(x)+\frac{1}{2}e^x$$

But  if I try to revserse it:

$$x= x -2\sin(x)+\frac{1}{2}e^x \implies 2\sin(x) = \frac{1}{2}e^x \implies 4\sin(x) = e^x \implies 4\sin(x)-e^x = 0$$

Can I just add $x$ and subtract like this? How it helps me in the iteration process?

Comment: Yes you can. Not all of these formulas will lead to convergence, and even then they may converge to different solutions. Did you try out any of these iterations with some small script, program or spreadsheet table?